# Will iRate automatically stop soliciting reviews after the user accepted?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa, irate

I am about to post my first app with irate, and I was wondering out of curiosity will it stop the pop up message by itself if the user rates it or is there some kind of special code that I need to put. Please answer only if you dealt with iRate for iPhone apps.
 https://github.com/nicklockwood/iRate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iRate pop up is only displayed once. If you will press the "Remind me later" button, it will appear again, but otherwise the user won't see it a second time.

Answer (score 0):

I have used iRate and this how it works.

If user rates a version then the Rate the App message will not be shown for that particular version. Suppose a new update comes, then the Rate message will start showing again.